# How does Godot manage to be fast with GDScript while Pygame is so slow with Python?

Tags: python, performance, pygame, godot

I see people complaining about how Pygame is so slow, having a backend with C and SDL and Godot seems to have a great performance even using a Python-like language.

Comment: GDScript was specifically designed to be efficient with their game engine [[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godot_(game_engine)#GDScript)], whereas Python is a general purpose language and isn't specifically optimised for game development.

Comment: also reading about what @Henry linked, it seems that Godot may be using the GPU since it uses OpenGl which _typically_ uses GPU, while Python uses only the processor

Comment: In the grand battle of "XYZ is slow you should write machine code", people forget that in games the GPU does a lot, and that once buffers and shader programs are loaded in the GPU, the programming language does not affect GPU performance. That is why you don't have to write in C++, games in C# can perform well. And you don't have to write in C#, games in GDScript can perform well. Until you do something particularity heavy on CPU logic, of course. Btw, GDScript runtime got improved for Godot 4.0, *although there are still bugs at the time of writing*, it should perform even better in stable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Godot is a game engine while Pygame is a cross-platform set of Python modules.

Game engines handle a lot of stuff related to game loop under the hood using a low level compiled language like C/C++. This means that developers can write scripts with higher level languages like C# or GDScript that contain methods that get invoked by the engine at certain points of the execution. The engine itself handles rendering, updating physics, polling for inputs and whatnot.

With Pygame you're likely writing the game loop yourself and calling bunch of libraries to poll for inputs, draw/render graphics, update physics etc. This means that a bigger chunk of the execution time gets spent executing python scripts than say GDScripts in Godot.